# Can the original Rpi run Chromium OS?

Tags: boot, chromium

I was trying to run chromium on my raspberry pi 1 but it won't boot. I do have it compiled for ARM processors but it still won't run. Am I doing something wrong or can it not run on something that old?

Comment: *"compiled for ARM processors"* -> There's ARM and then there's ARM.  The model 1 requires ARMv6 (there's actually ARMv6 and then ARMv6 too, but I think any such will work because the model 1 SoC is the most advanced form of ARMv6 so will be backward compatibility with all of them). However, by far the most prevalent version is **ARMv7**, so if you have a generic "arm 32-bit" compile it most likely that, which will not work.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Anyone know where to find a precompiled ARMv6 image, a tool to compile it easily for either Linux or Windows, or instructions to do it myself?

Comment: I doubt it very much. I believe there might have been at one time, but that doesn't mean it is still hanging around online somewhere. I've been here for six or seven years and if that is representative, there have never been more than a handful of Chromium OS users regardless of the model.

Comment: You probably need to read this article if you want it to run on ARMv6: https://www.cnx-software.com/2012/04/19/building-chromium-os-for-raspberry-pi-armv6/ However, after you compile the code, you must use an ARMv6 OS debugger otherwise it won't work.